# Why is access to the path denied?

Tags: c#, asp.net, io, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I am having a problem where I am trying to delete my file but I get an exception.

```
if (result == "Success")
{
     if (FileUpload.HasFile)
     {
         try
         {
              File.Delete(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + app_settings.login_images + txtUploadStatus.Text);
              string filename = Path.GetFileName(btnFileUpload.FileName);
              btnFileUpload.SaveAs(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + app_settings.login_images + filename);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
               Message(ex.ToString());
         }
      }
}
```

Also I should note that the folder I am trying to delete from has full control to network services.

The full exception message is:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\gowdyn\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\hybrid\hybrid\temp_loginimages\enviromental.jpg' is denied. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.File.Delete(String path) at hybrid.User_Controls.Imgloader_Add_Edit_Tbl.btnUpdate_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\gowdyn\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\hybrid\hybrid\User_Controls\Imgloader_Add_Edit_Tbl.ascx.cs:line 242

Any ideas?

Comment: What isn't clear about the exception? The account that the application  is running under does not have access privileges to the file/folder.

Comment: I understand what the exception is saying. The problem is this functionality is used by a some users who need to modify images using the system. Part of that is replacing images by deleting the old image and saving a new image.

Comment: Check your access permissions to the folder. 
give the proper permissions to the folder using security tab from properties window

Comment: The exception is not informative at all.  It doesn't tell you:

A. What principal is trying to access the resource
B. What permission does it need.

To find out, it requires installing Windows SysInternals and monitoring the path access.

Comment: You shouldn't be deleting files from the Visual Studio project folder in your application. If this is a temporary file, save it to and delete it from the [temporary folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettemppath).

Answer (score 298):

According to [File.Delete Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx)...

An `UnauthorizedAccessException` means one of 4 things:

- The caller does not have the required permission.
- The file is an executable file that is in use.
- Path is a directory.
- Path specified a read-only file.

Comment: I checked the file and rights, everything seemed fine. I checked the user. I could delete the file manually via Explorer. It turns out that it was a read only file. I am not sure why that should matter on the delete, as it was not in use. Anyway, all I did was add some code: if (myFile.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReadOnly))
{
   myFile.Attributes-= FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
}
myFile.Delete();

Comment: or simply: myFile.Attributes = myFile.Attributes & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;

Comment: Echoing Outside the Box Developer, I found that my own instance was a combination of the file being a read-only file, and use of the @ symbol with a path that already had the necessary escape characters.

Comment: Had this using `System.IO.FileStream.Init` and the file was read-only. Then why don't just read it? Removed read-only flag from the file and the exception was gone. Brilliant!

Comment: What does "Path is a directory" mean?

Comment: @Tris, it means that the path leads to a directory, not a file.

Comment: This is misleading, the exceptions should at least specify the reason either in the message, or better through a member.

Comment: I get this intermittently and not sure why. The only thing that might be related is that a file I am trying to rename (move) is extensionless and the could perhaps be interpreted as a directory?

Comment: Path is a directory was what I needed. I made the assumption that it would take on the name of the downloaded file by itself.

Answer (score 198):

I also had the problem, hence me stumbling on this post. I added the following line of code before and after a Copy / Delete.

**Delete**

```
File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
File.Delete(file);
```

**Copy**

```
File.Copy(file, dest, true);
File.SetAttributes(dest, FileAttributes.Normal);
```

Comment: I gave 'Everyone' full permissions to the folder without success.  Somehow these file attributes worked though. Thanks.  I wish MS would finally settle on a proper security model.  Trying to figure out why Copy/Delete explodes every few years is frustrating to say the least.

Comment: SetAttributes Normal was the trick for me - I was trying to File.Copy and overwrite a read-only file..

Comment: Access to the path is denied doesn't suggest that the file is simply readonly (since you do actually have access to the path!)
In my opinion the error message should be changed. Thanks for the hint anyways!

Comment: I ran the program as Administrator and the issue was gone.

Comment: Was running as admin and admin had full control over the directory and it still wouldn't save. This issue appeared to just crop up. That is, I was able to save and then all of a sudden it stopped working. Your answer worked though. I hope it's safe for TFS source control....

Comment: ^ FileAttributes.Archive makes it match the behavior of TFS for me

Comment: How does setting an attribute after a copy operation helps? Won't the program crash already on copy statement? Should it be before copy operation just like delete operation?

Comment: @VibhoreTanwer, the copy of the file creates a new file as it doesn't use the first file. Setting the attributes makes sure you can work with the file afterwards as it might be read-only or hidden. In order to delete the file it needs to be Normal attribute and if you want to do something with the copied file it has to be normal as well. By process of elimination we figured it out as it makes logical sense.

Comment: Old post, but thanks. I had the same trouble deleting temporary files that I copied to a folder where the user had full permissions. Setting each file's attributes to normal before deleting it stopped the UnauthorizedAccess exception from occurring.

Comment: How does one run the program as Administrator?

Comment: For me it was over zealous Norton AV blocking the write

Comment: This worked for me as well, but can anyone explain why it works?

Answer (score 38):

This is an old issue, but I ran into it while searching. Turns out that I was missing the actual filename component in the save path for SaveAs...

```
string uploadPath = Server.MapPath("~/uploads");
file.SaveAs(uploadPath); // BAD
file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(uploadPath, file.FileName)); // GOOD
```

Answer (score 24):

When a user tries to connect to your Web site, IIS assigns the connection to the **IUSER_ComputerName** account, where ComputerName is the name of the server on which IIS is running. By default, the **IUSER_ComputerName** account is a member of the Guests group. This group has security restrictions. Try to grand access to IUSER_ComputerName to that folder

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729264/what-are-all-the-user-accounts-for-iis-asp-net-and-how-do-they-differ) is very good described answer about IIS security

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks this helped.. Permission for IIS_IUSRS user.

Answer (score 22):

Right-click on Visual studio and click  **Run as Administrator**

Thanks for +1

Comment: This was the solution for my File.Move issue on a Windows 8.1 Enterprise machine on which I was local administrator, and nothing else had a handle on the files.

Answer (score 22):

I got the error because I didn't realize that the destination should be a file. I had a folder as the second parameter (which works in cmd). and I got `Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.` because C# `File.Move` wants a file there, not just for the first parameter, but for the second too, and so if you put a directory as second parameter, it's trying to write a file like `c:\crp` when you have a directory called `c:\crp`.

this would be **incorrect**  `File.Move(args[0],"c:\\crp");`

So, this would be **correct**    `File.Move(args[0],"c:\\crp\\a.a");`

The same goes for `File.Copy`

Comment: Thank you! This indirectly solved an issue where an API was expecting a destination which I gave as the directory, not realizing it had to include the filename (since the object itself has an associated filename).

Answer (score 11):

If this is an IIS website that is having the problem, check the Identity property of the advanced settings for the application pool that the site or application uses. You may find that it is set to ApplicationPoolIdentity, and in that case then this is the user that will have to have access to the path.

Or you can go old style and simply set the Identity to Network Service, and give the Network Service user access to the path.

Answer (score 7):

same issue for me too, 
I was pointing the folder instead of file.

so make sure in path, give path+filename

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("path", bytearray);
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to modify the privileges of the folder you're trying to delete from/save to. Right-click on the containing folder and use the Security tab to permit *modify* rights for the user your application runs under.

Comment: you are assuming that he is admin of his machine.. if this is a work machine and he's just a user .. they probably set the permissions up that way for a reason.. since we are only left to assume

Comment: It is a work machine and I am a power user. I don't log in as administrator. The properties of the image folder have been modified so network services has full access. But that didn't make any difference.

Comment: I just added "Everyone" with full access to the folder, and "voilá"

Answer (score 6):

An UnauthorizedAccessException exception is thrown when the operating system denies access because of an I/O error or a security error.

If you are attempting to access a file or registry key, make sure it is **not read-only**.

Answer (score 6):

I have also faced this issue when my window service started throwing the exception

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "C:\\Order\\Media
44aa4857-3bac-4a18-a307-820450361662.mp4" is denied.
```

So as a solution, I checked the user account associated with my service, as shown in below screen capture

[image]

So in my case it was **NETWORK SERVICE**

And then went to the **folder properties** to check if the associated user account also exists under their permission tab. It was missing in my case and when I added it and it fixed my issue.

For more information please check the below screen capture

[image]

Answer (score 5):

> The exception that is thrown when the operating system denies access
>   because of an I/O error or a specific type of security error.

I hit the same thing.  Check to ensure that the file is NOT HIDDEN.

Comment: Got Access Denied error when `FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)` was used and if file already existed and the file was hidden.

Answer (score 5):

I was trying to use System.IO.File.OpenWrite(path)

and it did not work because I was only passing OpenWrite() a path to a directory, but it requires a path all the way to the file you want to write. So a full path including the filename.extension at the end needs to be passed into OpenWrite to avoid UnauthorizedAccessException

Answer (score 5):

In my case the problem was Norton. My in-house program doesn't have the proper digital signature and when it tried to delete a file it gave the UnauthorizedAccessException.

[image]

If it give you a notification, you can handle it from there. In my case it didn't give a notification that I noticed. So here's how to keep Norton from blocking the program.

1. Open Norton
2. Click the down arrow
3. Click History
4. Find activity by program
5. Click More Options
6. Click Exclude Process

Answer (score 4):

Check your files properties. If the read-only is checked, uncheck it. This was my personal issue with the UnauthorizedAccessException.

Answer (score 4):

I got this error and solved it in just a moment. Don't know why all of my folders are read-only，I cancelled the read-only and apply it. However, it is still read-only. So I moved the file into the root folder, it works - so weird.

Comment: I cancelled the read-only, applied it, and it worked. As you say, the folder still shows as read-only afterwards for me too, but it solved it for me without need for further action.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing this error because

Sometimes when I `Combine` the *path* with *File Name* and `FileName = ""`

It become `Path Directory` not a `file` which is a problem as [mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24796126/4251431)

so you must check for `FileName` like this

```
if(itemUri!="")
        File.Delete(Path.Combine(RemoteDirectoryPath, itemUri));
```

Answer (score 4):

To solve this problem, I follow the Scot Hanselman approach at [Debugging System.UnauthorizedAccessException (often followed by: Access to the path is denied)](https://blog.elmah.io/debugging-system-unauthorizedaccessexception/) article, the code with example is bellow:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var path = "c:\\temp\\notfound.txt";
        try
        {
            File.Delete(path);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(path);
            if ((attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
            {
                attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
                File.SetAttributes(path, attributes);
                File.Delete(path);
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on a newly moved website on a shared server. Solved through the web host panel (DotNetPanel) setting true the "allow write permissions". So if you are in a shared server before reviewing all code worth taking a look at the server configuration and could save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that if you are trying to reach a shared folder path from your code, you dont only need to give the proper permissions to the physicial folder thru the security tab. You also need to "share" the folder with the corresponding app pool user thru the Share Tab

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact error when deleting a file. It was a Windows Service running under a Service Account which was unable to delete a .pdf document from a Shared Folder even though it had Full Control of the folder.

What worked for me was navigating to the Security tab of the Shared Folder > Advanced > Share > Add.

I then added the service account to the administrators group, applied the changes and the service account was then able to perform all operations on all files within that folder.

Answer (score 2):

For those trying to make a UWP (Universal Windows) application, file permissions are much more restricted, and in general is deny by default. It also supersedes the system user permissions. You will basically only have access to files in either

- Your install location
- Your AppData location
- Files selected through the [File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker) or [Folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker) picker
- Locations requested in your App Manifest

You can read more here for details => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions

Answer (score 2):

If you're using BitDefender there's a good chance its *Safe Files* feature blocked your operation. This is a form of Ransomware protection that comes with some of its more advanced versions.

Make sure to grant your application access in BitDefender and try again.

Some more details can be found in [this BitDefender support page](https://www.bitdefender.com/consumer/support/answer/2025/).

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was my AVG anti-virus that triggered the exception.

I added my VS Projects directory to the "Allowed" list. And I had to add the executable to the AVG exceptions list after I copied the `.exe` to my App directory.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in this direction - this was the issue for me too! Specifically, the AVG Ransomware Protection was the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem and I've managed to get it working by changing the partition on which the file will be saved. So, on line 5 I've changed @"C:\" to be @"D:\" and that resolved the problem.

```
static void SaveVideoToDisk(string link)
{
    var youTube = YouTube.Default; // starting point for YouTube actions
    var video = youTube.GetVideo(link); // gets a Video object with info about the video
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\" + video.FullName, video.GetBytes());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After migrating from `Visual Studio 2017` to `Visual Studio 2019` I faced two exceptions with two of my applications which run properly under `Visual Studio 2017`:

- System.UnauthorizedAccessException
- System.ArgumentException

It turned out that I had to add the executables of the two applications to the allowed apps of `Avast Antivirus`.

Comment: Solved my issue, thought I was going mad as I could save the file to the DIR but I couldn't overwrite it after restarting the program. Do you know if there is an alternative solution to adding an exception?

Comment: @MCC: Sorry, no, I stopped working on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same problem when trying to do this after deployment at server:

```
dirPath = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\website\\" + strUserName;
if (!Directory.Exists(dirPath))
{
    DirectoryInfo DI = Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
}
string filePath = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\Website\\default.aspx";
File.Copy(filePath, dirPath + "\\default.aspx", true);
File.SetAttributes(dirPath + "\\default.aspx", FileAttributes.Normal);
```

I granted permission in IIS to other group including administrator and my problem got solved.

Answer (score 1):

In my particular case I was repeatedly creating and deleting 10000 folders. It seems to me that the problem was in that although the method `Directory.Delete(path, true)` returns, the underling OS mechanism may still be deleting the files from the disk. And when I am starting to create new folders immediately after deletion of old ones, some of them are still locked because they are not completely deleted yet. And I am getting System.UnauthorizedAccessException: "Access to the path is denied".

[image]

Using `Thread.Sleep(5000)` after `Directory.Delete(path, true)` solves that problem. I absolutely agree that this is not safe, and I am not encouraging anyone to use it. I would love to here a better approach to solve this problem to improve my answer. Now I am just giving an idea why this exception may happen.

```
class Program
{
    private static int numFolders = 10000;
    private static string rootDirectory = "C:\\1";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(rootDirectory))
        {
            Directory.Delete(rootDirectory, true);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        CreateFolder();
        long time = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        Console.WriteLine(time);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void CreateFolder()
    {
        var one = Directory.CreateDirectory(rootDirectory);

        for (int i = 1; i <= numFolders; i++)
        {
            one.CreateSubdirectory(i.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First just check the path if the colon(:) character is missing or not after the drive letter. If colon is not missing then you can check if access/write permission is granted for that path.
I had the same issue and i was only missing the colon, permission and everything else was fine.

```
C:\folderpath
```

will work fine but,

```
C\folderpath .........(missing colon)
```

will give you access denial error.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this post as dealing with the same issue. Looks like the file is in use and hence not able to write to it. 
Though not able to figure it out, which process is using it. Signed out the other user who was logged in in that box, dont see any users who is holding it.
Any quick tips regarding on how to find the same.

Thanks,
Lakshay (developer)

Comment: In your answer don't post a new question, but try to answer the question of the original poster with helpful information. For your own question please search stackoverflow first for the same or similar questions. If you don't find any, post a new question following this guide: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

In my case file doesn't exist (it was a path to the Directory, without a file name, somePath/Directory)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this error can occur in DESIGN MODE as opposed to ? execution mode...
If you are doing something such as creating a class member which requires access to an .INI or .HTM file (configuration file, help file) you might want to NOT initialize the item in the declaration,  but initialize it later in FORM_Load() etc...
When you DO initialize... Use a guard IF statement:

```
    /// <summary>FORM: BasicApp - Load</summary>
    private void BasicApp_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Setup Main Form Caption with App Name and Config Control Info
        if (!DesignMode)
        {
            m_Globals = new Globals();
            Text = TGG.GetApplicationConfigInfo();
        }
    }
```

This will keep the MSVS Designer from trying to create an INI or HTM file when you are in design mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error thrown when I tried to rename a folder very rapidly after it had been either moved or created.

A simple `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);` solved it:

```
void RenameFile(string from, string to)
{
   try
   {   
      System.IO.File.Move(from, to)      
   }   
   catch 
   {  
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);      
       RenameFile(from, to);      
   }   
}
```

Comment: Think it would be better if you checked if the folder existed before moving it rather than sleeping for half a second... if the OS is busy the previous move might take longer than half a second, and your back to the same issue.

Comment: This piece of code is very dangerous. It repeats the RenameFile method no matter what exception is thrown! It could cause the app to crash if the cause of exception is an actual permission problem