# File.Copy Unauthorized access C#

Tags: c#, file, access-violation, unauthorized

I've started to encounter a problem with `File.Copy`. This works fine for my data creation script, managing to duplicate thousands of files with no issues. My problem occurs when trying to create temp files later in my code.

I have added the code sample below that isn't working correctly. I've tried numerous different ways to try to resolve this to no avail. What I am doing is copying some user data files created in a directory on the C drive into a temp folder inside that user data folder.

Code

```
foreach (string originalFile in OriginalDataFileNames)
{
    string tempFile = originalFile;
    TempDataFiles.Add(tempFile);
    Console.WriteLine("GlobalDataCtrl: Original Data File: " + XWSDataDirectory + "\\" + tempFile);
    Console.WriteLine("GlobalDataCtrl: Saved Temp Data File: " + tempPath + "\\" + tempFile);
    File.Copy(XWSDataDirectory + "\\" + originalFile, tempPath + "\\" + tempFile);
}
```

Exit Error

```
The program '[6256] XtremeWrestlingSim.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

SOLUTION:

```
FileStream outputFS = null;
            FileStream inputFS = null;
            outputFS = new FileStream(tempPath + "\\" + tempFile, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            using (inputFS = new FileStream(XWSDataDirectory + "\\" + originalFile, FileMode.Open))
            {
                inputFS.CopyTo(outputFS);
            }
            outputFS.Close();
            inputFS.Close();
```

Not sure how nicely formatted this is, but it works. Replace `File.Copy` with the above code.

Comment: Do you write these files yourself, and then later trying to copy them? Its possible that you're not closing a file handle somewhere. Make sure to use `using` statements or call `.Close()` any time you write a file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# UnauthorizedAccessException in File.Copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554108/c-sharp-unauthorizedaccessexception-in-file-copy)

Comment: I question why you are creating a new file (File.Create) and then copying an existing file over the top of it straight after (File.Copy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `File.Create` just before you call `File.Copy`, I think that is the issue, it is leaving an open stream.

Maybe removing the `File.Create` call will solve the issue. If not you could get the returned value (which is a stream) and close it before trying to copy.

> The file is opened with read/write access and must be closed before it can be opened by another application.

See remarks https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143361(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I usually just call `.Close()` at the end...`File.Create(tempPath + "\\" + tempFile).Close();`

Comment: Thanks bro! I just used the file stream instead of copy and it worked like a charm!!!!