# FileInfo.CopyTo() throws exception when trying to overwrite file

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, file-copying, unauthorizedaccessexcepti, system.io.fileinfo

I have the following piece of code in a .NET 6 app that copies some files to a different destination on the file system:

```
DirectoryInfo targetDir = GetTargetDir();
foreach (FileInfo fi in GetFilesToCopy())
{
    fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(targetDir.FullName, fi.Name), true);
}
```

As you can see, I'm passing `true` to the `.CopyTo()` method, so it overwrites the file if it already exists.
However, this seems to not work properly:

- If the destination file does NOT exist, the copy works fine
- If the destination file DOES exist, however, the copy operation fails and throws a `UnauthorizedAccessException` with an error message like `'Access to the path 'C:\my destination dir\my destination file.ext' is denied.'`

I've checked the method documentation, and it says that that exception is thrown if the destination is a directory or if we're trying to copy to a different drive. However, I'm not doing any of those things (and anyway it doesn't explain why it works if the file does not exist)

I've checked all I could think of, and it all seems in order:

- The user running the application has permission to write to that location and is the owner of the existing files
- The files are not in use, I can easily delete them using windows explorer or cmd
- I've also tried running the code as administrator (even though it shouldn't be needed) but same error occurs

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: What if you Delete the file first and then copy / move it?

Comment: Is the (existing) file read-only? Please check theese two: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554108/c-sharp-unauthorizedaccessexception-in-file-copy and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821410/why-is-access-to-the-path-denied

Comment: @nilsK: thanks, that was it, I had to remove the ReadOnly attribute. Do you know why the CopyTo() method sets the ReadOnly attribute when copying a file? Any way to avoid it?

Comment: If I am not wrong, you are trying to store the file to `C:` root level. 
To store file at `C:\` root level, you may have to run your process as `An Administrator`.

I think if you try to store it under user's folder such as `c:\users\[username]\my_destination_dir\my_destination_file.ext`, then it should work.

Comment: @S.Mishra: no, if you read my question you'll see I've already tried running as admin. The problem was a readonly attribute on the files.

Comment: @Master_T glad i could help. To your question: no i have no clue. It's a feature? ;)

Comment: @nilsK: I've done some more research, and apparently it just preserves the origin files' attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was the files have the Read Only attribute (thanks to @nilsK for pointing me in the right direction).

I've resolved this with the following code:

```
string destFile = Path.Combine(targetDir.FullName, fi.Name);
if (File.Exists(destFile))
{
    File.SetAttributes(destFile, FileAttributes.Normal);
}

fi.CopyTo(destFile, true);
```