# Login and Register using System.IO

Tags: c#, system.io.file

Don't Know What's wrong but I can't Access even It created a directory.. This is my code

```
private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("E:Praisey\\" + txtAcc.Text + "\\Login.ID");
        sw.Write(txtAcc.Text + "\n" + txtZipCode.Text);
        sw.Close();
    }
    catch(System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("E:Praisey\\" + txtAcc.Text + "\\Login.ID");
        var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("E:Praisey\\" + txtAcc.Text + "\\Login.ID");
        sw.Write(txtAcc.Text + "\n" + txtZipCode.Text);
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

it always getting error! The error is

> UnauthorizedAccessException  was unhandled
>
> Access to the path 'E:\Praisey\48492995\Login.ID' is denied.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821410/why-is-access-to-the-path-denied

Comment: well, maybe you are running with permissions that don't have access to that directory/file?

Comment: You are creating `"E:Praisey\\" + txtAcc.Text + "\\Login.ID"` directory and then creating `StreamWriter` to the same path... Also, you might not have access to `E:\Praisey` directory. Which line exactly throws the exception?

Comment: @tdragon in var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("E:Praisey\\" + txtAcc.Text + "\\Login.ID");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see from your catch block, `"E:Praisey\\" + txtAcc.Text + "\\Login.ID"` is actually a directory. You must also add the file name to the path.

```
var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("E:Praisey\\" + txtAcc.Text + "\\Login.ID\\filename.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs (had it yesterday too) when the `Directory` does not exist. You need to create it before starting your `StreamWriter`.

```
if (!Directory.Exists("E:Praisey\\" + txtAcc.Text))
    Directory.CreateDirectory("E:Praisey\\" + txtAcc.Text);
```