# File.WriteAllText() causes System.UnauthorisedAccessException XAML C#

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

Firstly, before anyone marks this question as a duplicate, read this. I read through many questions that are potential duplicates of this one, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821410/why-is-access-to-the-path-denied), yet none of the solutions that seemed applicable in my situation worked for me.

So, I have some code below to save text to a file (note: all variables have already been defined):

```
await Task.Run(() => File.WriteAllText(documentFile.Path, documentToSave));
```

But then, the a `System.UnauthorisedAccessException` is thrown at that line.

How can I fix this? Any solutions would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check that the documentFile.Path is a valid path, and that no other threads are using it

Comment: What is your documentFile.Path? You know the App Container contains your writing privilege within the app folder.

Answer (score 0):

Per the "win-universal-app" tag, assuming you are writing a universal windows app, please make sure you have read [File access permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt188700.aspx) and your app have **write right** to the file path.