# Access to windows path is denied when using file.copy() function in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am using `file.copy()` method to copy a file from source directory to destination directory in my vb.net windows application. and I am getting below error:

> Access to path '\sample\windows\path'  is denied.

```
Try
   If File.Exists(sourcepath) Then
      File.SetAttributes(sourcepath, FileAttributes.Normal)
   End If
   If Not Directory.Exists(dest) Then
      Directory.CreateDirectory(dest)
   End If

   File.Copy(sourcePath, destPath, True)
Catch ex As Exception
   System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Although I am able to access the specified windows path.I am running application with administrator privileges still i am getting this error.What can be the reason for this error.

Comment: Update your question with your code please. Also I don't like to assume so will ask, is **'\sample\windows\path'** the full path that your application is trying to copy to as that isn't a valid file path.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821410/why-is-access-to-the-path-denied)

Comment: @Jinx88909 I tried every solution listed there. like giving full permissions to that folder, sleep statements, running as administrator etc. but nothing worked for me..:(

Comment: It could be the file attributes rather than the file permissions. Would be better to have a look at your code too if possible

Comment: @Jinx88909 sure, i have edited the question with code..

Comment: OK thanks. Does the file already exist and it's trying to overwrite it?

Comment: no file doesn't exist there in destination.

Comment: The code looks OK to be fair so it will be something on the directory you are trying to copy too. Can you manually create a file in the directory as yourself or as administrator. Is this **sit_test** folder shared out? Just trying to understand the structure you have set up.

Comment: You can use the Effective Permissions dialogue within Windows to check the permissions on an object for a specific username. This could show whether the account you are making the connection with has appropriate rights to delete. See this [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771586(v=ws.11).aspx) article for details

Comment: @Jinx88909 Yes it is a shared folder and i am able to copy the same file from source to destination manually.. not getting what it is prompting error even after having proper access.