# C# Access denied to path

Tags: c#

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86);
File.WriteAllBytes(path, Properties.Resources.chargementvideo);
```

`chargementvideo` is a file in the resources of Vs.

So the access gets denied to 'ProgramFiles' and I've already tried to run as admin or to give full permissions.

Comment: Please provide links to the other solutions and explain why they don't apply to your situation.

Comment: are you running in an elevated process

Comment: You're trying to write to a *directory*. You need to append a file name to the path. Or at least that's part of your problem. You still may not have permissions to write directly into program files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is access to the path denied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821410/why-is-access-to-the-path-denied)

Comment: You know you haven't actually asked us a question?

Comment: It's already been stated that you're giving it the path to a folder. But just in case you put a filename on the end of that path.... "Program Files" is not somewhere that you as a programmer should be storing things. It will be secured against most users. Consider using an Application Data location, or why not just use the Temporary folder. (Path.GetTempPath()).

Comment: The path could be changed to Desktop or an other, that was just for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using [File.WriteAllBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx), uou must provide the path to a file as first argument, not to a folder... otherwise the method cannot know to which file data must be written to:

```
String file = 'data.ext';
String path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86);
String filePath = Path.Combine(path, file);

File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, Properties.Resources.chargementvideo);
```

Altrough I suggest you to avoid writing data into those folders... when accessing them, an elevation of privileges is necessary. You cannot do it programmatically, but you can make your application run with Administrative Rights by editing its manifest as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <v3:trustInfo xmlns:v3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <v3:security>
      <v3:requestedPrivileges>
        <v3:requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable"/>
      </v3:requestedPrivileges>
    </v3:security>
  </v3:trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, the thing is that i want to create a new file that is the chargementvideo from the resources, and not to edit a new one

Comment: No it didnt ^^ but i think we had a missunderstanding on what i'm trying to do but thank you for your help :)

Comment: Great, what is the current problem (besides trying to write bytes into a folder instead of a file)?

Comment: The access is still denied even whil trying to edit the "data" file, same error

Comment: Repeating my comment from above... It's already been stated that you're giving it the path to a folder. But just in case you put a filename on the end of that path.... "Program Files" is not somewhere that you as a programmer should be storing things. It will be secured against most users. Consider using an Application Data location, or why not just use the Temporary folder. (Path.GetTempPath()).

Comment: Actually, you should never write temporary files into that folder... but if you REALLY want to... you have to make your application run with Administrative Rights. You can't do it within your code, but you can request to elevate the rights of the assembly while it's running: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control#Requesting_elevation