# WebClient DownloadFile throws UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, webclient

I want to download some files and execute them in the `%temp%` folder but I get `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` when I try to run it:

> Exceção Sem Tratamento: System.Net.WebException: Exceção durante uma
>   solicitação do WebClient. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: O
>   acesso ao caminho 'C:\Users\Muni\AppData\Local\Temp' foi negado.    em
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   em System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>   em System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access)    em System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String
>   fileName)    --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha de exceções internas ---
>   em System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
>   em System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName) 
>   em encrypt.Program.Main(String[] args) na
>   C:\Users\Muni\source\repos\encrypt\encrypt\Program.cs

```
         try
        {
            string name = Environment.UserName;
            WebClient Client = new WebClient();
            string temp = "C:\\Users\\" + name + "\\AppData\\Local\\Temp";
            Client.DownloadFile("LINK", temp);
        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }
```

Comment: You are missing a "+" after name

Comment: okay i got the temp part working but when i compile it i get System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Comment: Have you actually looked at the `Message` property on the exception? Please edit your question to correct your code and to include the message from the exception.

Comment: @DaisyShipton btw thats the whole code from the program 
its console based and when the person opens it downloads some stuff into the %temp% folder and executes it

Comment: @DSADSADSADSA142 please use `try/catch` and [edit] your question with the full exception. like: `try { /* Put your code here*/ } catch (Exception ex) { string strError = ex.ToString(); }`. Add the content of "strError" in this question.

Comment: [File.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx) for one.

Comment: @DSADSADSADSA142 I don't want to be rude or something, but, since you speak Portuguese, you should ask here: [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Ah, you don't have a *file name* in your code. You need to include the name of the file in the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not supplying the file name in the path.

Here is an example of your mistake that I've written for testing:

```
    string name = Environment.UserName;
    WebClient Client = new WebClient();
    string path = "C:\\";
    Client.DownloadFile("https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png", path);
```

When I run it I get the same exception.

When I put a file name in the path it works correctly.

```
    string name = Environment.UserName;
    WebClient Client = new WebClient();
    string path = "C:\\test.png";
    Client.DownloadFile("https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png", path);
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821410/why-is-access-to-the-path-denied) has an answer that states that one of the causes of the `UnauthorizedAccessException` exception is "Path is a directory".