# Directory.Delete recursive interpreting a file as path (Access to the path 'file_without_extension' is denied

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, io

I'm trying to make an app to "Quick Format" an usb flash drive, it's all good until i put a file without extension (eg: `helloworld`).

I'm using `Directory.Delete(dir, true);` to achieve my goal, but recursive delete is interpreting `helloworld` as a directory instead of interpreting it as a file, so it throws Access to the path 'helloword' is denied.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. Directory.Delete is not confused by a filename without extension. The problem is in the permissions required to delete that file

Comment: Directory.Delete is deleting everything except `helloworld`, even though i can delete `helloworld` with File.Delete, but with recursive Directory.Delete i get this error

Comment: How are you determining that helloworld is a directory as opposed to a file?

Comment: IIRC, you'd see the same error if the file is locked by another application - I think I've even seen it cause by an antivirus ...

Comment: Thank you for your replies, but `helloworld` is a sample file, it's not open somewhere else, plus i don't use antiviruses

Comment: Sorry to be that guy but.... it works on my machine

Comment: and as someone has said Directory.Delete is not confused by a lack of file extension. Something must be locking the file

Comment: Does `File.Delete(dir\helloworld);` delete the file successfully or does it fail as well? Are you sure the file isn't [read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11523266/4934172)?