# Get access to windows folders in C#

Tags: c#, permissions, filesystems

I am making a software with Winforms and C# 7.0.
I have to get all the files in `C:\Program Files` and `C:\Program Files (x86)`.
When I try `Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Program Files\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories` I get an exception that the access to the path C:\Program Files\Common Files' is denied.

I tried to start my program as an administrator but it still doesn't work.
How can I get a list of all files in access-denied folders and read them?

Kind regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is access to the path denied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821410/why-is-access-to-the-path-denied)

Comment: The answers at this question don't work too

Comment: add app menifest file to your project use run as admin in configuration,or start visual studio as admin ,make sure you have administrative rights

Comment: Your program (or you) don't have the appropriate permissions to read those directories. You need to change that, or design your method in a way to skip the directories that you cant read

Comment: First of all I NEED to read the directories. Second I have administrative rights. I also changed the run as admin config in my app.manifest

Answer (score 0):

You will have to skip the directories you can't read (assuming that you can't run your program under the System account or other account with privileges to read all directories).

You have to be careful here because you can't use `yield` inside a `try/catch`. Here's one approach:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> EnumFilesRecursively(string rootDirectory)
{
    // Helper method to call GetEnumerator(), returning null on exception.

    IEnumerator<T> getEnumerator<T>(Func<IEnumerable<T>> getEnumerable)
    {
        try   { return getEnumerable().GetEnumerator(); }
        catch { return null; }
    }

    // Enumerate all files in the current root directory.

    using (var enumerator = getEnumerator(() => Directory.EnumerateFiles(rootDirectory)))
    {
        if (enumerator != null)
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                yield return enumerator.Current;
    }

    // Recursively enumerate all subdirectories.

    using (var enumerator = getEnumerator(() => Directory.EnumerateDirectories(rootDirectory)))
    {
        if (enumerator != null)
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                foreach (var file in EnumFilesRecursively(enumerator.Current))
                    yield return file;
    }
}
```

To test it:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var file in EnumFilesRecursively(@"C:\Program Files\"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Owns_Rekt In that case you will need to run your application with System credentials, otherwise it will not be permitted to enumerate the directory contents.