# How do I save my downloaded PDF file directly into a folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, pdf

I have set up the HelloSign API download method so that after I sign my document, it will automatically download into my folder. However, I am facing a problem where it does not let me download it into the folder.

I found out that there is an issue with the Windows 10 folder's read-only feature. I tried to disable it by following online tutorials but all did not work for me.

Here's an image of the error I got:

[image]

Here's my back-end code:

```
client.DownloadSignatureRequestFiles(reqid, @"C:\Users\Bryan\Documents\PDFFolder", SignatureRequest.FileType.PDF);
```

Comment: as exception clearly says: Permission is denied!

Comment: Check this `PDFFolder` as all the permission rights, [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821410/why-is-access-to-the-path-denied) will you you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the name of a file by which you are going to save the file and make sure you have `R & W` access to the specified folder, in your case it is <kbd>PDFFolder</kbd>

[GitHub Documentation](https://github.com/hellosign/hellosign-dotnet-sdk#download-a-signature-request-in-its-current-state-and-save-to-disk)

Try this:

```
client.DownloadSignatureRequestFiles(reqid, @"C:\Users\Bryan\Documents\PDFFolder\output.pdf", SignatureRequest.FileType.PDF);
```