# Copy files to C:\Program Files (x86)\ c# access denied when running application as administrator

Tags: c#, file, directory

I am creating an application that reads a `.txt` file with a list of files to copy to different locations and to overwrite the files if they already exist,  one location is:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\`

When doing this I am getting the following error:

`System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msado27.tlb' is denied.`

I am running my application as an Administrator and I have updated my applications manifest file to invoke the application as an Administrator user. However I am not sure why I am still getting this error even running as an Administrator?

To copy the files I am using the .Net file operations:

`File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);`

Full code section that deals with the file copying for your reference:

```
 void readFilesToInstall()
        {
            // 1 Read FileToInstall.txt Line By Line from C:\Temp2\BarsInstaller
            // 2 each line read copy to correct location
            // 3.  update progress bar 

            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Temp2\BarsInstaller\FilesToInstall.txt");
            string sourcePath = @"C:\Temp2\BarsInstaller\";
            progressBar.Invoke((Action)delegate
            {

                progressBar.Maximum = lines.Length;
                progressBar.Value = 0;
                lblPercent.Text = "0%";

            });

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] col = line.Split('=');
                //process col[0], col[1], col[2]
                string fileName = col[0];
                //string sourceFullName = source + fileName;
                DirectoryInfo fileCopyToLocation = new DirectoryInfo(col[1]);
                string sourceFile = Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
                string destFile = Path.Combine(col[1], fileName);
                darkLabel2.Invoke((Action)delegate
                {

                    darkLabel2.Text = destFile;

                    darkLabel2.Refresh();

                });

                copyFilesToInstall(sourceFile, destFile, fileCopyToLocation);
                progressBar.Invoke((Action)delegate
                {

                    progressBar.Value++;


                });


            }

        }

        void copyFilesToInstall(string sourceFile, string destFile, DirectoryInfo target)
        {
            if(Directory.Exists(target.FullName) == false)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);
            }





            File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
        }
```

Comment: Running an app as an administrator doesn't grant you permission to all files and directories. Check if you actually have write permission for that path and your admin account.

Comment: Areyou running your program from Visual Studio or using .exe file?

Comment: OK I think I may have found the issue some files are owned by the TrustedInstaller group, any ideas how I can copy my files?

Comment: Here this questions and aswers may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821410/why-is-access-to-the-path-denied