# getting System.UnauthorizedAccessException on File.Create

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm getting System.UnauthorizedAccessException when trying to create a file using

```
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
```

this is only trace i got

```
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

It's ASP.NET Core 6 Web API run on docker

Any Ideas? Thanks :)

EDIT:
Here is mu complete malfunctioning code snippet:

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "Uploads");
if(!Directory.Exists(filePath))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);

using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
    await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
```

Comment: because you dont have write access to that path seems to be the obvious explanation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is access to the path denied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821410/why-is-access-to-the-path-denied)

Comment: Check the security of the specific path you have declare, Make sure that you have authorize to access the specified path. Goodluck and happy coding :)

Comment: Your answers seems logical, however, the specified folder is created by the application itself. My guess is that it has authorization to access the Uploads folder because of that.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to create this file into systems folders or similar? Did you try to change your filePath to, let's say your images folder? You need to be sure that you've access rights to write into this folder, otherwise, you might have some issues with Windows permissions.

Comment: Hi I just made an Edit prividing folder path :)

Answer (score 1):

Just solved. I didn't put file name in the path.